# sometimes failed to read frame from rtsp with opencv and dnn

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I got a strange issue.
my code is quite simple, just read frame from RTSP and do some processing.

```
for (;;)
{
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    // heavy_processing(frame) // 
    imshow("cam",frame);
}
```

the rtsp streaming is a webcam with 1920x1080P, network traffic is arround 4Mb/s

without "heavy_processing()" function, basically it runs good. CPU is 45% (i7-7700)

with "heavy_processing()" function, it will read an empty frame after couple seconds then exit. I can see CPU surge to 95%+ before it exit.

I built opencv(3.4.3) myself with mostly default option.

so far I suspect the videocap device shutdown when there are too much frames in the buffer, but it doesn't make sense.shouldn't it drop the earliest frame? or is it possible the frame is corrupted inside 'heavy_processing()'?

ffmpeg probably is 4.0(built myself), ubuntu 16.04

the heavy_processing function:

```
void detect(Mat frame,vector<cv::Rect> &face_rects) {
    Mat detectFrame;
    cv::resize(frame, detectFrame, cv::Size(300, 300), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);
    dnn::blobFromImage(detectFrame, blob, 1.0, inpSize, mean, false, false);
    // if I return here is good
    net.setInput(blob);
    Mat detection = net.forward();   // as long as I add the last two line, it will cause read frame empty
```

ldd result:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeb5f9b000)
libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5fd796000)
libprotobuf.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9 (0x00007fe5fd454000)
libcppkafka.so.0.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcppkafka.so.0.2 (0x00007fe5fd18c000)
libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5fcf74000)
libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5fcd27000)
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5fc664000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5f9d50000)
libopencv_core.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4 (0x00007fe5f8e49000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe5f8ac7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe5f87bd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe5f85a7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe5f81dd000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe5f7fbf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563d8f116000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe5f7da5000)
librdkafka.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/librdkafka.so.1 (0x00007fe5f7a9d000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe5f7451000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe5f719c000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fe5f6e88000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe5f6c65000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe5f6a12000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe5f6701000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe5f64f8000)
libdc1394.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22 (0x00007fe5f6282000)
libavcodec.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.58 (0x00007fe5f4d93000)
libavformat.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.58 (0x00007fe5f494b000)
libavutil.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.56 (0x00007fe5f46d7000)
libswscale.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libswscale.so.5 (0x00007fe5f4458000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fe5f41fe000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fe5f3fd9000)
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fe5f3d65000)
libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007fe5f3b0f000)
```

Comment: ffmpeg is 4.0(built myself),and I found 95%+cpu is actually spread over multiple cpus(dnn did that?)

Comment: maybe you have framedrops or dropped packets and that's why no image can be decoded? Can you try to not break automatically on the first unsuccessful read, but try a few longer, whether one of the next maybe 50 frames can be decoded again?

Comment: no, it will keep reading empty frame, suspect it is related to dnn part, I added more information in the question, thanks

Comment: finally I found a solution:
I split these tasks into 3 threads:capture, process, display, I use thread-safe queue to communicate among these threads.the problem was gone now.
so far I suspect heavy cpu load will cause opencv to lost connection with rtsp streaming